# Trying to find the max with sum

Tags: sql, sum, max

I want just the max number of totalquantity displayed.  This gives me the whole list.

```
select 
      sum (consumes_t.quantity) as totalquantity
        , consumes_t.item_id

from

    consumes_t

group by
      consumes_t.item_id
```

I think they want us to use a subquery but I'm new to this and just not getting it at all.

Comment: If you want overall sum, you don't need to group. The above query is actually telling you how many units are available for each item.

Comment: Are you saying you want both the `sum` and the `max` of `quantity` for each `item_id`?

Comment: Can you give us some test data and expected outcome so we dont need to guess what you are trying to do.

Comment: What flavor of SQL are you using? (MySQL? SQL-Server?)

Comment: I have to determine which item was consumed the most.  I don't know how to paste my results in here, it's just coming up as a big mess when I copy and past from sqlserver.  I can get a list of a total of all the times an item was consumed and the id, but I just want one row that says which was consumed the most.  I'm sorry I'm so hopeless at explaining this.

Answer (score 1):

I'm not finishing to understand what you want, but if you want the max quantity do it on the same query:

```sql
SELECT SUM(consumes_t.quantity) as totalquantity, 
       MAX(consumes_t.quantity),
       consumes_t.item_id
FROM consumes_t 
GROUP BY consumes_t.item_id
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
select MAX(sum (consumes_t.quantity))) as totalquantity
        , consumes_t.item_id

from

    consumes_t
```

Answer (score 0):

For sqlserver, I think you would use `TOP 1` rather than the limit posted below:

```
SELECT TOP 1 SUM(quantity) AS totalquantity
      ,item_id
  FROM consumes_t
  GROUP BY item_id
  ORDER BY SUM(quantity) DESC LIMIT 1;
```

But what behaviour do you want if there are several items that have the same MAX?  Then use the subquery approach rather than the limit or top.

```
postgres=# CREATE TABLE consumes_t(quantity int, item_id int);
CREATE TABLE
postgres=#
postgres=# INSERT INTO consumes_t VALUES(2, 1);
INSERT 0 1
postgres=# INSERT INTO consumes_t VALUES(3, 1);
INSERT 0 1
postgres=# INSERT INTO consumes_t VALUES(1, 2);
INSERT 0 1
postgres=# INSERT INTO consumes_t VALUES(1, 3);
INSERT 0 1
postgres=# INSERT INTO consumes_t VALUES(1, 3);
INSERT 0 1
postgres=# INSERT INTO consumes_t VALUES(10,4);
INSERT 0 1
postgres=# INSERT INTO consumes_t VALUES(7, 5);
INSERT 0 1
postgres=#
postgres=#
postgres=# SELECT SUM(quantity) AS totalquantity
postgres-#       ,item_id
postgres-#   FROM consumes_t
postgres-#   GROUP BY item_id;
 totalquantity | item_id
---------------+---------
            10 |       4
             5 |       1
             7 |       5
             2 |       3
             1 |       2
(5 rows)


postgres=#
postgres=# SELECT SUM(quantity) AS totalquantity
postgres-#       ,item_id
postgres-#   FROM consumes_t
postgres-#   GROUP BY item_id
postgres-#   ORDER BY SUM(quantity) DESC LIMIT 1;
 totalquantity | item_id
---------------+---------
            10 |       4
(1 row)
```

Here is a subquery approach returning both records where two items total 10:

```
INSERT INTO consumes_t VALUES(3, 5);

WITH totals AS (
    SELECT SUM(quantity) AS totalquantity
           ,item_id
       FROM consumes_t
       GROUP BY item_id
)
SELECT t.item_id, t.totalquantity
  FROM totals t
  WHERE t.totalquantity = ( SELECT MAX(totalquantity)
                              FROM totals )
  ORDER BY item_id
```